# PHP problem with getimagesize()

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

I'm using the getimagesize() function in PHP and it keeps returning an error:

> getimagesize(image.php?name=username&pic=picture) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I'm not doing anything strange with it. The only problem I can imagine is that the path URL is another PHP script that returns a page with an image header, and there is an ampersand in that URL.

Here is my code:

```
$location = "image.php?name=username&pic=picture";
$size = getimagesize($location);
```

Comment: oh come on, someone has to know this

Comment: you asked it 8 minutes ago. chill.

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting the php script to get executed? In that case you shouldn't try to open the file directly (it wont be executed)
you should do something like

```
$location = "http://server.com/image.php?name=username&pic=picture";
$size = getimagesize($location);
```

Comment: Am I crazy? I just saw two other answers come and disappear while I was typing...

Comment: But then I get errors about direct URL something or other not being enabled on the server. I ran into that once with a different function and I know how to fix it, but I'd rather not as it makes things less secure.
But the thing is, why shouldn't it execute from the relative directory path?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I really wasn't sure about it.

Comment: @RobHardgood: Because it's not treating it like a URL with a query string, it's treating it as a local file with the name `image.php?name=username&pic=picture`.

Comment: I see... Is there any way around this besides using the full path, which is less secure and won't necessarily always be static?...

Comment: It doesn't get executed because you aren't callyng the php interpreter. getimagesize does a direct file open operation (he doesn't know you are trying to open a script, he expects a image file. Thats why you need to add the protocol (http).
The error is a php.ini configuration. You should change it to be able to use getimagesize in that way (it's something on the lines of allow_remote_file_open or something like that, I can't remember it right now)

Comment: you could user curl to call the php script. And write a temporary image file with the output...

Comment: I had a thought, is there any way I could run the getimagesize function in my image.php script, and then pass the values through somehow?...

Comment: the comment section doesn't allow me to paste too much text...
But here's what you need http://ar.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: getimagesize works with direct file open when you give it a local file, so in this case, there is no way.
The way of doing this with getimagesize is specifying a full URL (or with the help of curl)